# Angular 7 : Can't bind to 'element' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: javascript, angular7

I am getting below error when trying to run the Angular Code:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'element' since it isn't a known property of 'app-server-element'.
1. If 'app-server-element' is an Angular component and it has 'element' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-server-element' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements" [ERROR ->][element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@5:71
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11143)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25476)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25464)
    at compiler.js:25408
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25408)
    at compiler.js:25321
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25320)
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements" [element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'TestServer', content: 'Just a test !'}];
}
```

**server-element.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('srvElement') 
  element: { type: string, name: string, content: string };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**server-element.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>
      <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'sever'" style="color: red">{{ element.content }}</strong>
      <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**server-element.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('srvElement') 
  element: { type: string, name: string, content: string };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

cockpit.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {
  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddServer() {
    // this.serverElements.push({
    //   type: 'server',
    //   name: this.newServerName,
    //   content: this.newServerContent
    // });
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    // this.serverElements.push({
    //   type: 'blueprint',
    //   name: this.newServerName,
    //   content: this.newServerContent
    // });
  }
}
```

**cockpit.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>Add new servers or blueprint !</p>
    <label>Server Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
    <label>Server Content</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent">
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddServer()">Add Server</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddBlueprint()">Add Server Blueprint</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input('srvElement') 
element: { type: string, name: string, content: string };
```

Your input is called `srvElement`.

```
<app-server-element [element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
```

And you're trying to bind to `element` input, which doesn't exist.

But you shouldn't be renaming inputs anyway, just change to:

```
@Input()
element: { type: string, name: string, content: string };
```

Without `Input` decorator parameter, input and class property will be the same, as they should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the params into `@Input()`

Actually your input is named `srvElement` and not `element`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above methods seems to solve the problem:
**Ensure that all your components are registered in the app.modulte.ts**

Answer (score 0):

Though we know its a property of the app-server-element as we defined it as a property and its public also but still we are unable to access it. This happens because all properties of the components are only accessible inside the components and not from outside and its a very good thing because we don't want all our properties bindable from outside. Hence for this we have to be explicit about which property we want to expose outside. Hence to allow our parent component to be able to bind this property, we need to add something to that element property i.e, decorator. @input decorator should be used here.

```
@Input() element: {}
```

Also make sure that you import Input from @angular/core